# Why is getInitialState not being called for my React class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using ES6 classes with Babel. I have a React component that looks like this:

```
import { Component } from 'react';

export default class MyReactComponent extends Component {
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      foo: true,
      bar: 'no'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="theFoo">
        <span>{this.state.bar}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It doesn't look like `getInitialState` is being called, because I'm getting this error: `Cannot read property 'bar' of null`.

Answer (score 60):

The developers talk about ES6 class support in the [Release Notes for v0.13.0](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#es6-classes). If you use an ES6 class that extends `React.Component`, then you should use a `constructor()` instead of `getInitialState`:

> The API is mostly what you would expect, with the exception of getInitialState. We figured that the idiomatic way to specify class state is to just use a simple instance property. Likewise getDefaultProps and propTypes are really just properties on the constructor.

Comment: It took me a few minutes to figure this out, so I wanted to share this as a Q&A since I couldn't find anything on Google.

Comment: Yep, getInitialState is just any generic function at this point

Answer (score 31):

Code to accompany Nathans answer:

```
import { Component } from 'react';

export default class MyReactComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      foo: true,
      bar: 'no'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="theFoo">
        <span>{this.state.bar}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand a bit on what it means

> getDefaultProps and propTypes are really just properties on the constructor.

the "on the constructor" bit is weird wording. In normal OOP language it just means they are "static class variables"

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {
    static defaultProps = { yada: "yada" }
    ...
}
```

or

```
MyClass.defaultProps = { yada: "yada" }
```

you can also refer to them within the class like:

```
constructor(props) {
    this.state = MyClass.defaultProps;
}
```

or with anything you declare as a static class variable. I don't know why this is not talked about *anywhere* online with regards to ES6 classes :?

[see the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes).