# Class extends React.Component can't use getInitialState in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm tring the ES6 syntax in React, and write the components like:

```
export default class Loginform extends React.Component {
    getInitialState() {
        return {
          name: '',
          password: ''
        };
    };
}
```

but the browser throws me a waring about:

> Warning: getInitialState was defined on Loginform, a plain JavaScript
>   class. This is only supported for classes created using
>   React.createClass. Did you mean to define a state property instead?

I can handle it with the traditional syntax `var Loginform = React.createClass` but what's correct ES6 syntax?

Another little thing, I think in traditional syntax `React.createClass` is an object, so the functions in it is separated by comma, but with the `extends` class it require semicolon, I don't understand it well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is getInitialState not being called for my React class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31709258/why-is-getinitialstate-not-being-called-for-my-react-class)

Comment: @FelixKling sure. sorry

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You don't need semicolons or commas between ES6 class method declarations.

For ES6 classes, `getInitialState` has been deprecated in favor of declaring an initial state object in the constructor:

```
export default class Loginform extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      name: '',
      password: ''
    };
  };
}
```

Comment: With this, when `console.log(this.state.name)`, it throws an error about `Cannot read property 'state' of null`

Comment: Where are you trying to call it? In ES6 classes `this` is not automatically bound, which might be part of the problem: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding

Comment: Quoting from the linked article: "_One of the niceties provided by React's `createClass` functionality was that it automatically bound your methods to a component instance. For example, this meant that within a click callback `this` would be bound to the component. With the move to ES6 classes, we must handle this binding ourselves. The React team recommends prebinding in the constructor._" http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/refactoring-react-components-to-es6-classes

Comment: I kinda liked it the way it was with ES5 - and getInitialState()

Answer (score 7):

ES6 example: state, defaultProps, propTypes

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
export default class Item extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            check:false,
        };
        this.click=this.click.bind(this);
    }
    click(){
       this.setState({check:true});
    }
    render(){
        const text=this.state.check?'yes':'no';
        return(<div onClick={this.click}>{this.props.name} : <b>{text}</b></div>)
    }

}

Item.defaultProps={
    comment:"default comment",
};
Item.propTypes={
    name:React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If we use class field, following is working.

```
state = {
      name: '',
      password: ''
}
```

This can be used instead of

```
constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      name: '',
      password: ''
    };
  };
```