# Warning: getInitialState was defined on DimensionPicker, a plain JavaScript class. This is only supported for classes created using React.createClass

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to write my first react control. Here is what I have written

```
import React from 'react';
import DimensionPickerAction from '../actions/DimensionPickerActions.js';
import MovieLensAppStore from '../stores/MovieLensAppStore.js';

class DimensionPicker extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { items: [], currentItem: '' };
    }

    getInitialState() {
        this.state = {
            items: MovieLensAppStore.getAttributes(this.props.dimension),
            currentItem : MovieLensAppStore.getCurrentAttribute(this.props.dimension)
        };
    }

    onSelectionChange(newValue) {
        DimensionPickerAction.selectionChange(this.props.dimension, newValue);
    }

    render() {
        var optionNodes = this.state.items.map((item) => {
            if (item === this.state.currentItem) 
                return(<option value="{item}" selected>{item}</option>)             
            else
                return(<option value="{item}">{item}</option>)
        });
        return(<div><select onchange="onSelectionChange">{optionNodes}</select></div>);
    }

}

export default DimensionPicker;
```

Very surprisingly, I get an error

```
Warning: getInitialState was defined on DimensionPicker, a plain JavaScript 
class. This is only supported for classes created using React.createClass. Did 
you mean to define a state property instead?
```

I find this very confusing because clearly my component derives from React.Component

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447149/class-extends-react-component-cant-use-getinitialstate-in-react, but briefly you just need to move what is in your `getInitialState` to the `this.state` assignment in the constructor.

Comment: I updated the code but it still gave the same error message. My whole code is here `https://github.com/abhitechdojo/MovieLensReact.git`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eric's comment is correct. You're using ES6 classes, which means that `getInitialState` is not supported. You'll need to change this:

```
class DimensionPicker extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { items: [], currentItem: '' };
    }

    getInitialState() {
        this.state = {
            items: MovieLensAppStore.getAttributes(this.props.dimension),
            currentItem : MovieLensAppStore.getCurrentAttribute(this.props.dimension)
        };
    }
```

to this:

```
class DimensionPicker extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: MovieLensAppStore.getAttributes(props.dimension),
            currentItem : MovieLensAppStore.getCurrentAttribute(props.dimension)
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this, if you like to save the initial state construction somewhere for later use:

```
class DimensionPicker extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._getInitialState = this._getInitialState.bind(this)
    this.state = this._getInitialState();
  }

  _getInitialState() {
    return { items: [], currentItem: '' }
  }
```