# React JS access states / props from another component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm new to React, I am unable to access `Login` component state in `Member` component:

**App.js:**

```
export default React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
               testp : ''
      }
  },
  componentDidMount() {    
      var abc = "asdadaddasad";
       this.setState({testp : abc})
  },
  render() {
        <div>
       <header>
            <div className="menu-trigger">
                <i className="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <div className="container">
                <ul className="fR clearfix">
                    <li><NavLink to="/" onlyActiveOnIndex>Home</NavLink></li>
                    <li><NavLink to="/members">Members</NavLink></li>
          <li><NavLink to="/register">Register</NavLink></li>
           <li><NavLink to="/login">Login</NavLink></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
        </header>
         <div className="content-row">
            <div className="container">
                 {this.props.children}
           </div>
        </div>
         </div>
   }
})
```

**Login.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import Member from './Member';
var Login = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      loginname : ''
    }
  },
  componentDidMount() {    
    var test = 'abc';
    this.setState({loginname : test});
  },
  render() {
    return <div>test</div>
  }
});
export default Login
```

**Member.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import Login from './Login';

var Member = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.loginname}</div>
            <div>{this.props.prop11}</div>
           <div>{this.props.testp}</div>
  }
});
export default Member
```

How do I access `Login` component state in another JS file? 
Could anyone please help me figure this out?

Comment: `getInitialState` is never called.. You never set `loginname` as prop...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33447222/58129

Comment: I'm not using ES6 classes.. in above example how to set loginname as prop,I'm new to react please help me sort this out

Comment: You are not doing anything with `Login`.... but either way, state is only accessible inside the component itself. How do you expect `this.props.loginname` to magically refer to `Login`'s state? (at least that's what I *think* you expect)

Comment: You cannot access one components state from another component unless you pass it as a prop to its child. If the components don't relate then you need to make use of Redux or Flux to maintain a global state that can be accesed from other components

Comment: Actually component state can be accessed via `component.state` if you attach a ref to it. But that's usually an anti-pattern.

Comment: Now you put `<Member prop11={test}/>` in some random place. What do you expect it to do there? You might want to follow the tutorial first to get more familiar with the basics: https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html .

Comment: but i imported Member class at top that doesn't enough to set state for that particular class?

Comment: i have menus, on clicking login submit i want to send loginstatus to members so that i can check their login status

Comment: You cannot call a jsx component directly in componentDidMount(). Please resolve that and post an edit for it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Lifting State Up

If you need to use a given state in two different components, chances are that state should live in a parent component which then passes it to the two (or more) components that need to use it.

So basically for your example, you'll need a component e.g. `App` on a higher level than `Login` and `Member` which holds that state for you. That component then passes the state as a prop to Login and `Member`, and passes functions to call to change that state as props as well.

**Pseudocode**

```
App
  state.loginname = ''

  handleLoginnameChange(login) {
    this.setState(loginname: login)
  } 

  render () {
    <Login loginname={this.state.loginname}
           handleLoginnameChange={this.handleLoginnameChange} />

    <Member loginname={this.state.loginname} />
  }
```

**Accessing the `loginname` state in child components**

The above makes it so that the `loginname` state on parent component `App` is passed as a prop to the `Login` and `Member` components, in which they are accessible as `this.props.loginname`.

**Modifying the `loginname` state from a child component**

When in `Login` you need to modify the `loginname`, you call `this.props.handleLoginnameChange(newLoginname)` with the appropriate arguments (the new `loginname` value)

You're invited to read more on this on React's docs: [Lifting State Up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: please check my updated post, I have app.js like above

Comment: my idea is after login send loginname to member.js file

Comment: Put `loginname` as state in `App` (can be the top component). Pass it as prop to `Login` and `Member`. Give those children components a prop `handleLoginnameChange` so that e.g. `Login` can be able to change the `state.loginname` on the `App`. After this you don't need to "send" anything anywhere, it all propagates through the props.

Comment: yes i understand, but if you look at my app.js i'm using Navlink for menu and im using {this.props.children} to render dynamically in there how to use your code?

Answer (score 0):

Component states are intended to be local and accessing it from other components is usually an anti-pattern.

There are a few strategies to go about inter-component communication as outlined in this article: [8 no-Flux strategies for React component communication](http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/)

In summary:

(1) If your components have a hierarchical relationship, then `Member` component should be imported within `Login` and `loginname` is passed as a `prop` to `Member`.

(2) If your components do not have a hierarchical relationship, you can lift the state up into their common ancestor component and pass data via callbacks and props.

The article above outlines common strategies for inter-component communication. Highly recommend that you check them out.

Comment: i did like that only can you check my updated post, can you say where i did wrong?

Comment: Your code is unformatted and very hard to read. I also don't think you have done your due diligence in reading up the React docs yet. Please do so before seeking further help.

Answer (score 0):

**This is shortest method for data sharing if you dont want to trigger/bind any event for your shared info.**

Just store your state as stringify value as hidden field in component render method and regenerate it in another component with `Jquery` and `JSON` parse.

**component A :**

`<input type="hidden" id="hdnFilterState" value={JSON.stringify(this.state.selections)} />`

**component B :**

`let selections = JSON.parse($('#hdnFilterState').val());`

Comment: If you're using jQuery in a React project my feeling is you're doing something very wrong... jQuery is literally no longer required, everything should be state-driven. I guess you *could* use it to read data from the DOM like you've just shown in a read-only sort of way, but I don't think anyone would advocate for that in a production project.