# react-native-maps - TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.state.region')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I got this error message when trying to embed `react-native-maps` functions.

```
react-native-maps - TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.state.region')
```

My code

Home.js

```
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

export default () => (
    <MapView 
    style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
    }} 
    region={this.state.region} 
    onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}
  />
);
```

index.js

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

/**/

  getInitialState() {
    return {
      region: {
        latitude: 37.78825,
        longitude: -122.4324,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
      },
    };
  }

  onRegionChange(region) {
    this.setState({ region });
  }

  render() {
    /**/
  }
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/datomnurdin/auth-reactnative

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I already got the answer. Create a new file to declare a new global variable and function.

Home.js

```
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import { onRegionChange, _values } from "./NewFile";

export default () => (
    <MapView 
    style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
    }} 
    region={_values.region}
    onRegionChange={() => onRegionChange() }
  />
  />
);
```

NewFile.js

```
export const _values = { 
  region: {
        latitude: 37.78825,
        longitude: -122.4324,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
      }
};

export const onRegionChange = (region) => {
     _values.region = region;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all  `getInitialState`  is deprecated. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447149/class-extends-react-component-cant-use-getinitialstate-in-react)

and working example.  https://snack.expo.io/@nazrdogan/mapview-example?session_id=snack-session-cSA-6uzo9

Second problem is `onRegionChange` function. you need to bind or use arrow function

Answer (score 0):

You don't have state in the context you are using it. i.e. the function in Home.js

What you should do is pass the `region` from your component as a prop in your Map stateless component.

**Moreover, the onRegionChange is also not available here so pass that too as a prop**

Your code should look like :

```
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

 export default ({region, onRegionChange}) => (
   <MapView 
     style={{
       position: 'absolute',
       top: 0,
       left: 0,
       right: 0,
       bottom: 0,
     }} 
     region={region} 
     onRegionChange={onRegionChange}
    />
    );
```

and when you use this in rendering use it like below from your component where you have the `region` state variable.

```
import MyMap from './Home' . //Assuming that the Map function is imported as MyMap name.
....
render() {
  ...
   <MyMap region ={this.state.region} onRegionChange ={this.onRegionChange} />
}
```

Also, you should not use `getInitialState` as its deprecated and should not be used with the `class` syntax.

You should initialize your state like this:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
   constructor (props) {
      super (props);
      this.state = {
       ...
       region: {
           latitude: 37.78825,
           longitude: -122.4324,
           latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
           longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
      },
     }
   }
}
```

Also, you have not binded your onRegionChanged function in your class, do it using ES6 `=>` operator.

```
onRegionChange = (region) => {
   this.setState({ region });
}
```

Comment: I already tried, no error message so far but it seems not to detect latitude & longitude for a map region.

Comment: @MohammadNurdin Can you verify that you are having region object with data before rendering in map function ?

Comment: how to verify it? i try this but nothing happened. 

onRegionChange = (region) => {
     alert(region);
     this.setState({ region });
  }